Drawing a background in css
I am trying to draw a shape for a background looking like an ellipse, it should be on the left side.
I am working on a blazor app, on the right side I created a responsive login but for the left side I have to put a background of the shape (like an ellipse)
I tried this but doesn't seem to do the job
/* Keyframes for the animation */
@keyframes slideFromLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes slideFromRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Styling for the left section */
.left-section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212D49;
    animation: slideFromLeft 1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards, fadeIn 0.5s ease-out forwards;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left-section::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    width: 150%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #212D49;
    clip-path: ellipse(50% 100% at 25% 50%);
}

/* Styling for the right section */
.right-section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: slideFromRight 1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards, fadeIn 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}


<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
        <div class="left-section">
            <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <!-- Placeholder for any content within the left section -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
            <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <EditForm model="@login" OnValidSubmit="@HandleLogin" class="@GetFormCssClass()">
                    <div class="light-login-container">....


But i think in your case is better use background-gradient.
